# Flatpickr and VueJS "self.config" error when trying to setDate()

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datepicker, onchange, flatpickr

I am having some issues with Laravel (*5.5.46*) + VueJS (*2.6.10*) + Flatpickr (*2.4.1*). 
What I try to do is, when I change the Date field I want to update Start Time and End Time fields with new values.

[image]

Here is the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "value": "TypeError: self.config is undefined" found in ---> <Datetime><BookingForm><Root> admin.js:41492:15

TypeError: "self.config is undefined"
    setSelectedDate          http://localhost/js/admin.js:103661
    setDate                       http://localhost/js/admin.js:103687
    value                           http://localhost/js/admin.js:101992
    run                              http://localhost/js/admin.js:45419
    flushSchedulerQueue http://localhost/js/admin.js:45163
    nextTick                      http://localhost/js/admin.js:42847
    flushCallbacks            http://localhost/js/admin.js:42773
admin.js:42755:13​
```

And here is the code that triggers the error (the block inside `this.datePickerConfig.onChange` event):

```
Vue.component("booking-form", {
  mixins: [AppForm],
  data: function () {
    return {
      form: {        
        datum: "",
        starttijd: "",
        eindtijd: "",
        tp_start: "08:00",
        tp_end: "18:00"     
      }      
    };
  },
  computed: {
    datePickerConfigAltered: function () {      
      let tConfig = {        
        noCalendar: true,
        enableTime: true,
        time_24hr: true,        
        enableSeconds: false,
        minuteIncrement: 0,        
        dateFormat: "H:i:S",
        altFormat: "H:i",
        defaultDate: "12:00",
        defaultHour: "12",
        defaultMinute: "00",
        minDate: "08:00",
        maxDate: "22:00",
      };

      var that = this;
      this.datePickerConfig.onChange = function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {          
        // START - Code causing VueJS errors
        let sd = flatpickr("#starttijd", tConfig);
        sd.jumpToDate();
        sd.setDate(that.form.tp_start, true, tConfig.dateFormat);

        let ed = flatpickr("#eindtijd", tConfig);
        ed.jumpToDate();
        ed.setDate(that.form.tp_end, true, tConfig.dateFormat);        
        // END - Code causing VueJS errors**
      };

      return this.datePickerConfig;
    }
  }
});
```

Thank you! :)